# Function with dynamic static fields

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typing

I need to write a type for function with dynamic static fields from the generic type

```
interface WithStatic<P, T extends string[]> {
  (props: P): void;
  [K in T]: WithStatic<P, T>; // TS Error: A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrDACwMpjmYBAHgAUAaZAFWQgA9IQATAZ2WbClAHMBtAXQB8yAN4AoZMgAUABygB7acwBcyEgEoVANznBGAbnHIeAaWSgqfFeiy58hUhUoC9yAPSuq2ZAFEo8qCoAgsgIcgC20gCukIzIsgrQYACeyCBwYShhkezIAEYocjDIydIoAOTsnCBcZRRlIJFh+VC1yBVJTXIANq1yUG1wIEllAHSiAL5AA)

If I move dynamic fields deeper (put it to another field), everything works:

```
interface WithStatic<P, T extends string> {
  (props: P): void;
  options: {
    [K in T]: WithStatic<P, T>;
  };
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrDACwMpjmYBAHgAUAaZAFWQgA9IQATAZ2WbClAHMA+ZAbwBQyZAAoADlAD245gC5kJAJQKAblOCMA3MOQyCUkPIG6RAbQDSyUFQC6C9Flz5CpCpR46RAXx3egA)

Example usage:

```
const withStatic = (props => {}) as WithStatic<{}, 'maybe' | 'ready'>;
```

Then typing

```
withStatic.options.
```

shows `maybe` and `ready`:

[image]

How can I define dynamic types at the root level of the interface instead?

**Edit**

[Playground link what I got in the result](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=53&pc=1#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-wwi20Wgg7ETkC+IDQFqtNviCbx8UNqby+D4OJZKcbqdw9UaUGBoMdfQ7qftWkFQ9TYe5h0IkY0szKaAA1hBTEYoMvTABCZCoWtgShj8fto95FTOuBiw8n-p7iZQKIXq9D1WDjtu195F+N5nMT-vvpep63oAALAIQAC0mIIJ8EB9F2wANEglbWhA8gdEwTBzNghBKD4EBgO2xqEg+-yfGijaECA3A0rMpDQocV54gSRIflA3DYCAVIQDKcr0uQv4dl2kB+DxtJ8QgAmNjIsbAKJ8r8a+X5QNQKpMO0GFEaakT4WkfZggA5OxnEQPpUAAD5QPpQkMsApkWfp0n-Pp8RoJR1F0nRUQxG2eFgKi6L4hoJrJg2eTwYhexUTRyY2GaUC+a5UV0vETFBYS76fmO-SGRxXHOZZ1l+PlDnSDJ+kCkw75AA)

Answer (score 3):

A mapped type can't contain any other declaration except the mapping expression (ie `[K in T]: ...`). Also it can't appear in an interface.

Taking this into account you will need to use an intersection in a type alias to describe the type you want. This will work:

```
type WithStatic<P, T extends string[]> = {
  (props: P): void;
} & {
  [K in T[number]]: WithStatic<P, T>; 
}

let c = ((p: {}) => 1) as any as WithStatic<{}, ['maybe', 'ready']>

c.maybe.maybe // not sure this is what you are going for here but it compiles..
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=65&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgZWAQ2HAxgHgAoA0UAKlBAB7AQB2AJgM5T3ABOc1A5gNoC6AfFAC8UAN4AoKFAAUYFgHsw9AFxQ8AShUA3OXFoBuMQF8oAMlESoXANJR2JLtQCuAWwBGEFjx4r4SVBmx8ImI+PSgjMTEAGwhgKCwhaRkVEUM1IQEARnS0RjRqEChc2AQUdExcVKIuAHJnNBB3GqIalgg0WhAa-kisADp6xogBhvcoAHpxqGo5OPpHNqgkOEYVqAB3RAwoEDlHIsWOHU4oADM5FihED2g+vqA)

While the type above works I am not sure it really makes sense, maybe you want the fields declared in `T` to be of a specific type (such as `string` or `any` or `boolean`) then you could just use the mapped type `Record`.  Also we usually pass in multiple keys as a union not as a tuple:

```
type WithStatic<P, T extends string> = {
  (props: P): void;
} & Record<T, string> // replace strign with whatever 

let c = ((p: {}) => 1) as any as WithStatic<{}, 'maybe' | 'ready'>

c.maybe = ""
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=13&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgZWAQ2HAxgHgAoA0UAKlBAB7AQB2AJgM5T3ABOc1A5gHxQC8UAbwBQUKAAowLAPZh6ALih4AlAoBuUuLQDcQgL5QAZFABKELFJa0cxIszaceAekdQWEMABs0WaHbgdqKAB3BERgxAwIVQgWKCEhDwhgKCw+cQkFAV0lPh4ARhy0RjRqECgi2FDUDGwcLKIAcgBbNBAAIwgGqAAfKAa3NFoQBq54rAA6FvbofgAiWaA)

**Edit**

With regard to the comment, you can allow `c.maybe.ready` but not `c.maybe.maybe` but then you will need to use a union then not a tuple:

```
type WithStatic<P, T extends string> = {
  (props: P): void;
} & {
  [K in T]: Exclude<T, K> extends never? string : WithStatic<P, Exclude<T, K>>; // Added bottom 
}

let c = ((p: {}) => 1) as any as WithStatic<{}, 'maybe' | 'ready'>

c.maybe.maybe // error
c.ready.maybe = ""
c.maybe.ready = ""
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=19&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgZWAQ2HAxgHgAoA0UAKlBAB7AQB2AJgM5T3ABOc1A5gHxQC8UAbwBQUKAAowLAPZh6ALih4AlAoBuUuLQDcQgL5QAZIJFQA2gGko7EgF0FAUXJYANgFdaEHMSLmeFKnSM1BCqECwA-Eys7BxQCvBIqBjY+ESOLu6e3lC+XFpQAPQFUACCtB60UABGUsDAUgC2UHpCQs4QwFBYfOISCgK6Snw8AIxDaIxo1CBQE7AIKOiYuANEAOQNaCBVEGtQAD5QaywQaLQga1ytWAB0m9sQd1s7hcVh0ixCtydnIE8PPQARICvv8djcfucgYCgA)

Comment: `I am not sure it really makes sense` – the original idea was to exclude the current field from the nested `WithStatic`. I mean that `c.maybe`, `c.maybe.repeat` or `c.repeat.maybe` are correct usage while `c.maybe.maybe`, `c.repeat.repeat` or `c.maybe.repeat.maybe` should thrown error. So I should exclude current filed `[K in T]: WithStatic<P, Omit<T, K>>; ` but this does not work.

Comment: Why is the `[number]` in `[K in T[number]]` necessary? I see that it is, but I totally fail to see why. :-)

Comment: @tuchk4 My original reading of the question was regarding mapped type syntax. It was not at all clear what you were trying to achieve. I think we can get what yo want to work, let me give it a shot ..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder because the type parameter passed in is a the tuple type `['maybe', 'ready']`, you cant map over `['maybe', 'ready']` you can map over `['maybe', 'ready'][number]` which will get you the union of item types in the tuple (that is `'maybe' | 'ready'`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - I *think* I get it, thanks. I can't wait until March/April next year when I can dive deep into a TypeScript book or two. :-) Don't suppose you've written one?

Comment: @tuchk4 I think the edit covers what you want.. not sure if I landed on your exact requirements.. let me know

Comment: @T.J.Crowder O I wish I had time for such a fun project. Between my 2 jobs, my hobby teaching job and my two kids there basically is no time left for much else except maybe a TS  PR now and then 

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes, this is exactly what I want to do :) Thank you a lot. BTW I did not clarify all things in the main post because I just wanted to know how to define dynamic static fields for function, but then faced more problems :) I added the link to the playground what I have in the result but there are still some type issues. Would be happy if you have time to review :)